# Redemption RDOFolderSynchronizer Not working on BackgroundWorker Thread

Tags: outlook-redemption

I am a long time Redemption coder, with several apps using Redemption on the background thread (but not using RDOFolderSynchronizer up to now).

I have a new rSession object created on the backgroundworker thread, to which I pass the MAPI Object.

```
 RedemptionCode rCodeBW = new RedemptionCode();
 rCodeBW.InitialiseRedemption(Globals.MapiObject, true);
```

On the background thread I am trying to use the RDOFolderSynchronizer but when I run it, I get an error when I try to retrieve the syncitems. The error is:

IMAPIFolder.OpenProperty(PR_CONTENTS_SYNCHRONIZER) returned MAPI_E_INTERFACE_NOT_SUPPORTED
Synchronization is only supported for the Exchange folders in the online mode.

If I run the same code in the main thread it works fine, so I 'think' the 'online mode' issue is not the direct reason it is failing.

The code I am using is:

```
var MAPI_NO_CACHE = 0x200;
var MAPI_BEST_ACCESS = 0x10;
RDOFolder2 rFolder2 = rSession.GetFolderFromID(entryID, storeID, MAPI_NO_CACHE ^ MAPI_BEST_ACCESS) as RDOFolder2;
RDOFolderSynchronizer synchronizer = rFolder2.ExchangeSynchronizer;
RDOSyncMessagesCollection syncItems = synchronizer.SyncItems(Globals.UserSettings.LastSyncDataEmailInbox);
```

Any suggestions gratefully received.

Comment: Forgot to say I am using Redemption version 5.15

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that interface has to be used on the same thread where the parent MAPI session (`IMAPISession`) is created. It is an ICS API limitation in Extended MAPI.

Comment: Thanks Dmitry. Lightening fast response as always.

Comment: Can I get the SyncItems collection on the main thread, and then process them on a background thread? E.g. just pass the collection and then go get the items on the background thread from the entryIDs?

Comment: That should work. Or you can get the entry ids into your own list and use it on the secondary thread.